# Relation in Laravel 9 : ErrorException Attempt to read property “main_group_name” on null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, foreign-keys, relationship

so i was try to make 1 to many relationship between 'MainGroup' model and 'Group' model. FYI, I've changed the default id for each model. So I'm no longer using default id anymore.

here's my 'Group' migration

```
Schema::create("mst_item_group", function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->integer('code_group')->primary();
            $table->foreignId('code_main_group');
            $table->string('group_name');
            $table->timestampsTz();
            $table->string('created_user');
            $table->string('updated_user')->nullable();
        });
```

here's my 'Group' model

```
class Group extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'mst_item_group';
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $primaryKey = 'code_group';
    public $incrementing = false; 

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'code_group';
    }

    public function mainGroup()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(MainGroup::class, 'code_main_group');
    }
}
```

here's my 'MainGroup' migration

```
 Schema::create('mst_item_main_group', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->string('kode_barang')->primary();
            $table->integer('code_main_group')->unique();
            $table->string('main_group_name');
            $table->timestampsTz();
            $table->string('created_user');
            $table->string('updated_user')->nullable();
        });
```

here's my 'MainGroup' model

```
class MainGroup extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'mst_item_main_group';
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $primaryKey = 'kode_barang';
    public $incrementing = false; 


    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'kode_barang';
    }

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Group::class, 'code_main_group');
    }

    protected static function newFactory()
    {
        return MainGroupFactory::new();
    }
}
```

but when I try to call 'main_group_name' column via 'mainGroup' function, it gives me this kind of error

```
<p>Main Group : {{ $group->mainGroup->main_group_name }}</p>
```

[image]

so for a moment, I just handling this error with this

```
<p>Main Group : {{ $group->mainGroup->main_group_name ?? $group->code_main_group }}</p>
```

so that's from me, I really appreciate any kind of help from everybody. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your migration doesn't provide any link between the tables, your foreign keys are not defined correctly. This database schema is quite a mess regardless.

Comment: @miken32 is it because my foreign key in 'Group' migration has the same name as other column in 'MainGroup' migration? (which is 'code_main_group')

Comment: You aren't defining a foreign key at all. [Read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) on what the `foreignId()` method does. You're really making life difficult by not following expected naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

When not using laravel's default naming convention you should give the belongsTo method both the foreign_key and the owner_key like the following:

```
return $this->belongsTo(
    MainGroup::class, 
    'code_main_group', // foreign_key
    'code_group' // owner_key
);
```

I hope this was your solution.
Best regards.